# Calling a function when pressing less than not pressing comma

Tags: javascript, function, textarea, keycode

please help me i want to call a function when pressing **less than(<)** not pressing **comman(,)**

```js
 function tag(event)
    {
     var x = event.keyCode;
        if (x == 188)
     {
            alert ("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

```html
<textarea cols="50" rows="25" onkeyup="tag(event)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Come on.. You just forgot using semi-colon. onkeyup="tag(event);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add one more condition to check whether shift keyy pressed or not using `event.shiftKey`

```js
function tag(event) {
  var x = event.keyCode;
  if (event.shiftKey && x == 188) {
    alert("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="50" rows="25" onkeyup="tag(event)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you Friends for helping me

Answer (score 0):

my friend. You can refer my suggestion:

```
if(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 188){
            alert('Hello');
    }
```